# TSQL- generate a sequence number for duplicate records

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2000

Using SQL Server 2000, consider a source table with more than 400,000 records.

The task is to select each `regno` entry with an incrementing on-the-fly `rowid` or sequence number for those with duplicates or multiple entries. For those which do NOT have duplicate entries in the source table, the `rowid` should simply be `null`.

Here's an example of the desired output:

```
    regno   rowid
    100      1
    100      2
    100      3
    200      null
    300      4
    300      5
    400      null
    500      null
    600      6
    600      7
```

**Question:**
What query would do the desired sequence incrementing using TSQL in SQL Server 2000?

Comment: do you mean INSERT as you said (into a new table from an existing one), or is it really an UPDATE?

Comment: I think the OP means UPDATE. That would make sense from the data and request.

Comment: RANK is the only ranking function available on 2000 that I'm aware of - this link is the best I could find for generating a rowid, but it won't allow you to skip rows: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/186133

Answer (score 2):

If my comment is correct (600 should be 6,7) then have a look at this

```
DECLARE @Table TABLE(
        regno INT,
        rowid INT
)

INSERT INTO @Table (regno,rowid) SELECT 100, NULL
INSERT INTO @Table (regno,rowid) SELECT 100, NULL
INSERT INTO @Table (regno,rowid) SELECT 100, NULL
INSERT INTO @Table (regno,rowid) SELECT 200, NULL
INSERT INTO @Table (regno,rowid) SELECT 300, NULL
INSERT INTO @Table (regno,rowid) SELECT 300, NULL
INSERT INTO @Table (regno,rowid) SELECT 400, NULL
INSERT INTO @Table (regno,rowid) SELECT 500, NULL
INSERT INTO @Table (regno,rowid) SELECT 600, NULL
INSERT INTO @Table (regno,rowid) SELECT 600, NULL

DECLARE @TempTable TABLE(
        ID INT IDENTITY(1,1),
        regno INT
)

INSERT INTO @TempTable (regno)
SELECT  regno
FROM    @Table

SELECT  regno,
        CASE 
            WHEN (SELECT COUNT(1) FROM @TempTable WHERE regno = t.regno) = 1 
                THEN NULL 
            ELSE (SELECT COUNT(1) FROM @TempTable WHERE regno = t.regno) - (SELECT COUNT(1) FROM @TempTable WHERE regno = t.regno AND ID > t.ID) +
            (SELECT COUNT(1) FROM @TempTable WHERE regno < t.regno AND regno IN (SELECT regno FROM @TempTable GROUP BY regno having COUNT(1) > 1))
        END Val     
FROM    @TempTable t
```

Answer (score 0):

The query to extract the non-unique records would be

```
select regno,count(*) from table group by regno having count(*) > 1
```

I don't know enough about MSSQL to tell you how to generate an incrementing sequence number to update the records that match the query.

Answer (score 0):

Without a temp table:

```
DECLARE @Table TABLE(
        regno INT
)

INSERT INTO @Table (regno) SELECT 100
INSERT INTO @Table (regno) SELECT 100
INSERT INTO @Table (regno) SELECT 100
INSERT INTO @Table (regno) SELECT 200
INSERT INTO @Table (regno) SELECT 300
INSERT INTO @Table (regno) SELECT 300
INSERT INTO @Table (regno) SELECT 400
INSERT INTO @Table (regno) SELECT 500
INSERT INTO @Table (regno) SELECT 600
INSERT INTO @Table (regno) SELECT 600

select regno, null as rowid from @Table group by regno having count(*) = 1
union 
select regno, row_number() OVER (ORDER BY a.regno) as rowid
   from @table a
   where regno in (select regno from @table group by regno having count(*) > 1)

regno       rowid
----------- --------------------
100         1
100         2
100         3
200         NULL
300         4
300         5
400         NULL
500         NULL
600         6
600         7
```

Oops - did not see that you want to do this in SQL 2000 until after posting this ... ignore my query please. In SQL 2000 you need a temp table to generate the sequence.